# RStudio crashes when invoke file.choose()

Tags: r

Errors occur randomly when trying to execute:

```
myFile <- file.choose()
myData  <- read.csv(myFile, header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

However

`myData <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=FALSE, sep=",")`

works stable. What's wrong with the first implementation?

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Comment: Seems like this might be a better for [Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com). There's no good reason those should be different far as R code goes. At least share your version number and `sessionInfo()` and any other details to increase the chances of making the error reproducible.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for advice. Added sessionInfo(). RStudio Version 0.99.446.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue on the same versions. Check Help -> Diagnostics -> Show log files maybe you'll find the error message.

Comment: Issue still unresolved. Rstudio support is of no help. Log file shows:

`19 Jun 2015 02:24:39 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 232 (The pipe is being closed); OCCURRED AT: void rstudio::core::http::AsyncClient<SocketService>::handleWrite(const boost::system::errorcode&) [with SocketService = boost::asio::windows::basicstream_handle<>] C:/Users/Administrator/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/AsyncClient.hpp:316; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const rstudio::core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:287`